# Syntax in this SQL Trigger to insert into another table mixing data from inserted rows and other data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

For example, I am trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO 
   [LNK_54SD_Reporting].[54_SD_Membership].[Users] (ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate) 
VALUES 
   (@ApplicationId, @UserGuid, [inserted].[email], 0, 0)
```

but I get the error that `inserted.email` could not be bound.

By suggestion, I have also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    [LNK_54SD_Reporting].[54_SD_Membership].[Users] 
    (SELECT 
         ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate) 
VALUES  
    (@ApplicationId, @UserGuid, i.[email], 0, 0 FROM INSERTED)
```

which gives me an error on the SELECT

What is the property syntax to get data from the inserted row on a insert trigger when I am trying to also insert other data as well?

Comment: where are you getting the 'other data'?

Comment: @Randy @ApplicationId is hardcoded value assigned to the variable and @UserGuid is just a `NEWID()` assigned to the variable @UserId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your information...

```
 INSERT INTO [LNK_54SD_Reporting].[54_SD_Membership].[Users] 
 (ApplicationId, UserId, UserName, IsAnonymous, LastActivityDate) 
 SELECT @ApplicationId, @UserId, inserted.email, 0, 0
 FROM INSERTED
```

Although perhaps LastActivityDate should be `Null`?